# Is there any R function which can convert binary data to column?

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| number | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0.4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

and I want to have this data frame:

| number | category |
| --- | --- |
| 0.3 | B |
| 0.3 | D |
| 0.4 | A |
| 0.4 | B |
| 0.4 | C |

Is there any way or function that can help me to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pivot_longer` to get the data in long format and `filter` the values that are not 0.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -number, 
               names_to = 'category') %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  select(-value)

# number category
#   <dbl> <chr>   
#1    0.3 B       
#2    0.3 D       
#3    0.4 A       
#4    0.4 B       
#5    0.4 C
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in reproducible format.

```
df <- structure(list(number = c(0.3, 0.4), A = 0:1, B = c(1L, 1L), 
    C = 0:1, D = 1:0), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot. You are right I had to use reproducible data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another strategy:

1. assign values to columns with `across` and `case_when`
2. remove `number` column with `.keep="unused"`
3. remove NA's

```
library(dplyr)
librayr(tidyr)

df %>% 
    mutate(across(A:D, ~case_when(. == 1 ~ as.numeric(number))), .keep="unused") %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = A:D, 
        names_to = "category",
        values_to = "number"
    ) %>% 
    na.omit()
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  category number
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 B           0.3
2 D           0.3
3 A           0.4
4 B           0.4
5 C           0.4
```